# Get 7 days data with Hive

Tags: hive

i have one table with different date

```
2014-11-20
2014-12-12
2014-11-10
2014-12-13
2014-10-12
2016-01-15
2016-01-14
2016-01-16
2016-01-18
```

want the last 7 days data (max date -7)

```
2016-01-15
2016-01-14
2016-01-16
2016-01-18
```

I have tried with below query but did not work

```
select * from date_txt1 where DATEDIFF((select max(purchase_date) from date_txt1),(select min(purchase_date) from date_txt1)) <= 7;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "datediff" as second parameter use just column name:

```
select * from date_txt1 
where DATEDIFF((select max(purchase_date) from date_txt1), purchase_date) <= 7;
```

Updated: "max" extracted:

```
with maxDate as (
    select max(purchase_date)  as end_date
    from date_txt1
)
Select * 
From date_txt1 , maxDate
where DATEDIFF(maxDate.end_date, purchase_date) <= 7;
```

Comment: Hi @pashaz thanks for the help but i got failure message                                                  FAILED: ParseException line 1:40 cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'max' in expression specification

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.purchase_date 
from date_txt1 a
cross join ( select max( purchase_date ) as maxdate from date_txt1 ) b
where DATEDIFF( b.maxdate, a.purchase_date ) <= 7
```